# Use regular expression with Javascript RegExp constructor

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression like this and it works fine using https://regexr.com/

([a-zA-Z0-9-.*~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(/[a-zA-Z0-9-.*~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?|(/[a-zA-Z0-9-.*~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+/?)(?[a-zA-Z0-9-.*~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?

I would like to use it with RegExp() like below(I just put the above string inside the raw string), but it does not work. Do I need to do any other treatment?

```
const pattern =String.raw`([a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+\/?)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(\#[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?`;
let re = new RegExp(pattern);
return re.test(somestring)
```

I also tried enclose the regex with / and / like below and it does not work either. It allows spaces but I don't really allow space.

```
const re = new RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+\/?)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(\#[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?/);
```

Updates:
I guess my question should be how do I make sure it matches full text like what I can do test in the website above(attached screenshot below)
[image]

Comment: What string does it work with in regexr but not in code?

Comment: Like if I have ``` or space in code, it treat it as valid but not in website above

Comment: Ok, Can you include some sample successful/failed input strings in the question?

Comment: If we can't easily [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the issue, it's unlikely to get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root of this question is that regexr is matching on the full string rather than just a part. `.test()` will return true if part of the regex matches. if you want to only return true when matching the on the full string I would suggest using start `^` and end `$` delimiters.

````js
const pattern =String.raw`^([a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+\/?)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(\#[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?$`;
let re = new RegExp(pattern);
console.log(re.test('asdf```'))
````

Answer (score 1):

Match the beginning `^` and end `$` of a string to get an exact match, otherwise a substring will be accepted.

```
const re = new RegExp('^regex$')
```

On the sample string:

```
const reStr = `^([a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+\/?)(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?(\#[a-zA-Z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?$`
```